# Click() is not performing on Fb message(left panel) and Home button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I tried different xpath (relative and absolute) and perform `.click()` on them in Facebook message (left panel) and Home button on upper nav bar but the element is highlighted (like when you hover the mouse pointer on it) but not clicking on them.
My code snippet is like this:

```
d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_59g8']/div[@class='clearfix']/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='pinnedNav']/ul[1]/li[2]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

After login fb page. You can try with the below lines of code, it will perform click action on **Home** and **Message** Button.

```
  d.findElement(By.linkText("Home")).click();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  d.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Messages")).click();
```

Comment: Hi @Saritha G , thanks for the answer. You code worked but in the message part, I need to click on Left panel "Messages" but as per you xpath it is clicking on upper nav bar message icon. But I tried this xpath //span[.='Messages']/. and it worked .

Comment: yes.you can also use this //div[@class='linkWrap hasCount'], this xpath will also works for that.